# Unable to build develop environment for Geonetwork 3

Tags: ubuntu, geonetwork

I've been trying to build Geonetwork development environment using the steps from https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/tree/develop/software_development

Here is the stacktrace, when building **common utils**:

```
INFO] [findbugs:check {execution: default}]
[INFO] BugInstance size is 1
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] Total bugs: 1
[INFO] Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown in org.fao.geonet.utils.nio.NioPathAwareCatalogResolver.resolve(String, String) ["org.fao.geonet.utils.nio.NioPathAwareCatalogResolver"] At NioPathAwareCatalogResolver.java:[lines 32-117]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] failed with 1 bugs and 0 errors 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: failed with 1 bugs and 0 errors 
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:719)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalWithLifecycle(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:556)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoal(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:535)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoalAndHandleFailures(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:387)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:348)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: failed with 1 bugs and 0 errors 
    at org.codehaus.gmaven.mojo.GroovyMojo.fail(GroovyMojo.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:230)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:912)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:78)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.findbugs.FindbugsViolationCheckMojo.execute(FindbugsViolationCheckMojo.groovy:521)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultPluginManager.java:490)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.executeGoals(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:694)
    ... 17 more
```

Here is the output from `mvn -v`:

```
Apache Maven 2.2.1 (rdebian-14)
Java version: 1.7.0_80
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux" version: "3.13.0-57-generic" arch: "amd64" Family: "unix"
```

Using Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 64.

I've already deleted my /home/.m2 directory,and even tried from a fresh vagrant box with Ubuntu 12.04 with the same error.

Also tried for the branch 3.0.x and 3.0.1 tag, all of them seems to fail.

Any ideas, on how to get the development environment up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's weird, you have the same environment as me and I can do it.

Did you install the jdk version of Java or only the jre? Try javac -version to check it.

Check also with this steps: https://www.geocat.net/how-to-compile-and-run-geonetwork/

**UPDATE:** As stated in this issue you should use Maven 3 https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/1111#issuecomment-123562337

Comment: I have jdk installed, `javac -version` outputs `javac 1.7.0_80`.


Also checked the `java` and `javac` being used by default, they are `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/bin/java` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/javac`

Comment: The difference between your steps and what i did is the mvn command. I'll try `package install` skiping tests instead of `clean install` with tests.

Comment: `package install` now works!!!! Had to replace Maven 2.2.1 to Maven 3.2.1. Was getting `[FATAL ERROR] org.codehaus.groovy.maven.plugin.execute.ExecuteMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) and may be out-of-date` when Building GeoNetwork schema plugins. Thanks for the help