# Build geonetwork: FileNotFoundException rebel.xml

Tags: geonetwork, maven

Just tried to build geonetwork on my ubuntu machine, following [this](http://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/trunk/eng/users/tutorials/introduction/deployment/build.html) and [this](http://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/developer/development/) tutorial.

Unfortunately I ran into a problem, I don't know how to fix.
I managed to get the geonetwork clone from github and did

> mvn package install -DskipTests

This finished the build of `common utils` with an error, after having done all the downloads. Here's the stacktrace from running with -e switch.

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] GeoNetwork opensource ............................. SUCCESS [0.341s]
[INFO] common utils ...................................... FAILURE [0.756s]
[INFO] Caching xslt module ............................... SKIPPED

...

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.5:generate (generate-rebel-xml) on project common: Failed writing rebel.xml: /srv/git/repos/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/common/target/classes/rebel.xml (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.zeroturnaround:jrebel-maven-plugin:1.1.5:generate (generate-rebel-xml) on project common: Failed writing rebel.xml
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed writing rebel.xml
        at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.maven.GenerateRebelMojo.execute(GenerateRebelMojo.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /srv/git/repos/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/common/target/classes/rebel.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
        at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.maven.GenerateRebelMojo.execute(GenerateRebelMojo.java:220)
```

Any ideas how to create the missing rebel.xml or work around it? Tried `mvn clean` and `mvn clean install` as well, but without success.

**UPDATE:**
I updated maven version from 3.0.4 to 3.3.9, which was helpful according to [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154894/unable-to-build-develop-environment-for-geonetwork-3?rq=1), but without success, I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I got several different error messages, it seemed that the folder target could not be created during the build (there were no errors on failed creation of the directory). So the build failed due to missing permissions and I built with `sudo`, which worked fine.